# UWP - PointerExited is not fired when Grid is in Listview

Tags: win-universal-app, listviewitem, uwp-xaml

I want to show a image in the listview, and the pointer is over the image, I will display the filesize/filename and a download button at the bottom of the image. And I also can open the file by tap the image.

I registered the PointerEntered and PointerExited event of the control, and tried to show or hide the filesize/filename/download button when the events get fired.

When the finger touch the image, the PointerEntered is fired. However, on touch screen(Phone, tablet), when the finger left the image, the PointerExited event is not fired. When I operate with mouse on tablet, everything is working correctly.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<Grid>
                        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerEntered" >
                                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowFileInfoCommand}"></Core:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerExited" >
                                <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HideFileInfoCommand}"></Core:InvokeCommandAction>
                            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ThumbnailUri}" Stretch="{Binding ImageStretch}" MaxHeight="200" MaxWidth="350" Height="{Binding FileHeight}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped" >
                                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ConversationRoom.OpenFileFlipViewCommand,Source={StaticResource Locator}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="RightTapped">
                                    <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RightTappedMessageCommand}"/>
                                </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </Image>
                        <Grid Background="White" Opacity="0.75" Height="50" x:Name="InfoGrid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="{Binding NeedShowFileInfo, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisible}}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="6,0,0,6" Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="6,0,0,6" Text="{Binding FileSize}"/>
                            <FontIcon  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,6,6" Glyph="&#xE82F;" FontFamily="../Assets/fontello.ttf#fontello">
                                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"/>
                                    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </FontIcon>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
```

And if I move the Grid out of the listview, but in a stackpanel/Grid, everything goes fine.

Can anyone help on this issue?
Thank you!

Comment: In touch screen you can make it hide when user taps on other image

Comment: Actually the `PointerEntered` should also not fired when on mobile, the `ListView` will catch the pointer event first and not pass it to its children, so maybe you can do with pressed/tapped event.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, as I said I need to open the image when I tap/press it, so I can't use pressed/tapped event.

Comment: Then maybe we can only catch the events on ListView and calculate the offset of the `Scrollviewer` inside the ListView, and find the match item. Sorry I can't find any better solution now.